# Time complexity of finding a key by value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, hashmap, time-complexity, big-o

I know that looking up a hash value by key is `O(1)` (constant time) but is it the same if you find the key that has a certain value?  I'm looking up the key using:

```js
const answer = Object.keys(dict).find(key => dict[key] === 1);
```

`dict` is an object that has integer keys.

Comment: No, that would be O(n) time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

That's `O(n)` time complexity, since you're performing a linear search on an array (the array returned by `Object.keys`). At worst, the item you want will be the last item in the array (or it won't be in the array at all), which would require `n` operations to determine (`n` being the length of the array) - hence, it's `O(n)` time.

Comment: And even in the best case, where the target value is the first item, `Object.keys()` will have a time complexity of `O(n)`

Comment: @Bergi so would it be more efficient to iterate with a `for...in` loop rather than using `Object.keys`? (note I'm asking about raw time efficiency in ms, not big O)

Comment: Probably. On the other hand, js engines might be able to optimise the `Object.keys()` pattern into an iterator as well - you'd have to benchmark it.

Comment: Alright, interesting - thanks!